# Symfony2 OAuth Client

Tags: php, symfony, oauth

I am trying to add this oauth client library "adoy/oauth2" to symfony to connect with my OAuth2 enable API. This is what I have done so far.

1) composer.json

> ```
> "require": {
>     "adoy/oauth2": "dev-master"
> }
> ```

2) AuthController.php

> // src/Test/WebBundle/Controller/AuthController.php
>       namespace Test\WebBundle\Controller;
>
> ```
> use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
>
> // these import the "@Route" and "@Template" annotations
> use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
>
> use OAuth2;
>
>
> class AuthController extends Controller
> {
>     /**
>      * @Route("/authorize", name="auth")
>      */
>     public function authAction(Request $request)
>     {
>         $authorizeClient = $this->container->get('test_web.authorize_client');
>
>         if (!$request->query->get('code')) {
>             return new RedirectResponse($authorizeClient->getAuthenticationUrl());
>         }
>
>         $authorizeClient->getAccessToken($request->query->get('code'));
>
>         return new Response($authorizeClient->fetch('https://api.test.me/me'));
>     }
> }
> ```

3) OAuth2Client.php

```
// src/Test/WebBundle/Service/OAuth2Client.php
namespace Test\WebBundle\Service;

use OAuth2;

class OAuth2Client
{
    protected $client;
    protected $authEndpoint;
    protected $tokenEndpoint;
    protected $redirectUrl;
    protected $grant;
    protected $params;

    public function __construct(OAuth2\Client $client, $authEndpoint, $tokenEndpoint, $redirectUrl, $grant, $params)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->authEndpoint = $authEndpoint;
        $this->tokenEndpoint = $tokenEndpoint;
        $this->redirectUrl = $redirectUrl;
        $this->grant = $grant;
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function getAuthenticationUrl() {
        return $this->client->getAuthenticationUrl($this->authEndpoint, $this->redirectUrl);
    }

    public function getAccessToken($code = null)
    {
        if ($code !== null) {
            $this->params['code'] = $code;
        }

        $response = $this->client->getAccessToken($this->tokenEndpoint, $this->grant, $this->params);
        if(isset($response['result']) && isset($response['result']['access_token'])) {
            $accessToken = $response['result']['access_token'];
            $this->client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            return $accessToken;
        }

        throw new OAuth2\Exception(sprintf('Unable to obtain Access Token. Response from the Server: %s ', var_export($response)));
    }

    public function fetch($url)
    {
        return $this->client->fetch($url);
    }
}
```

4) CredentialsCommand.php

```
// src/Test/WebBundle/Command/CredentialsCommand.php
namespace Test\WebBundle\Command;

use OAuth2;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class CredentialsCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('oauth2:credentials')
            ->setDescription('Executes OAuth2 Credentials grant');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $credentialsClient = $this->getContainer()->get('test_web.credentials_client');
        $accessToken = $credentialsClient->getAccessToken();
        $output->writeln(sprintf('Obtained Access Token: <info>%s</info>', $accessToken));

        $url = 'http://oauth-server.local/api/articles';
        $output->writeln(sprintf('Requesting: <info>%s</info>', $url));
        $response = $credentialsClient->fetch($url);
        $output->writeln(sprintf('Response: <info>%s</info>', var_export($response, true)));
    }
}
```

5) Finally services.yml which is something wrong I think

```
parameters:
    adoy_oauth2.client.class: OAuth2\Client
    test_web.class: Test\WebBundle\Service\OAuth2Client

services:
    adoy_oauth2.client:
        class: %adoy_oauth2.client.class%
        arguments : [%oauth2_client_id%, %oauth2_client_secret%]
    test_web.credentials_client:
        class: %test_web.class%
        arguments : [%adoy_oauth2.client.class%, %oauth2_auth_endpoint%, %oauth2_token_endpoint%, %oauth2_redirect_url%, 'client_credentials', {client_id:%oauth2_client_id%},{client_secret:%oauth2_client_secret%}]
    test_web.authorize_client:
        class: %test_web.class%
        arguments : [adoy_oauth2.client, %oauth2_auth_endpoint%, %oauth2_token_endpoint%, %oauth2_redirect_url%, 'authorization_code', {redirect_uri:%oauth2_redirect_url%}]
```

The Error:

ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Test\WebBundle\Service\OAuth2Client::__construct() must be an instance of OAuth2\Client, string given, called in C:\wamp\www\myproj\app\cache\web_dev\appWeb_devDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1460 and defined in C:\wamp\www\myproj\src\Test\WebBundle\Service\OAuth2Client.php line 16

I am just out of idea now after trying a few times tweaking services.yml? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Symfony2 does not have a way to specify a service id in service arguments using `%parameter%` syntax. In YAML config, you should use `@service_id` syntax for service arguments.